# Calculating a Sum

Tags: vba, excel

What I am trying to do is develop a model that takes a cell that is greater than 1 then to take the sum of the area to the first row using a cone shape, so for example cell D4, sum the area C3:C5 + B2:B6 + A1:A7.

At the moment I have this but it obviously is not working.

```
    Dim I As Double
    Dim J As Double
    Dim Size As Integer
    Dim x As Integer
    Dim y As Integer
    Dim z As Integer
    'Dim Range As Integer
    Dim PV1 As Integer





    'MCArray = Worksheets("Data")
    I = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Worksheets("Data").Rows(1))
    J = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Worksheets("Data").Columns(1))


    'Loop to Move down the rows
    For x = 1 To J
        'Loop to move acoss the columns
        For y = 1 To I
            'IfElse to determine if cell value is greater or equal to zero
            If Cells(J, I).Value >= 0 Then
                'Loop to sum the cells above
                For z = 1 To J
                    PV1 = (ActiveCell.Value) + Worksheet.Sum(Range([J - z], [I-z:I+z]))
                    'IfElse to determine if final sum is greater than zero
                    If PV1 > 0 Then
                        Worksheets("MC").Range("B4").Value = PV1
                        Range([J - z], [I-z:I+z]).Interior.ColourIndex = 1

                    End If
                Next z
            End If
        Next y
    Next x
```

Comment: PV1 = (ActiveCell.Value) + Worksheet.Sum(Range([J - z], [I-z:I+z]) Brings up the error message Range of object failed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a function you can use either as a UDF or from another routine. Just pass it the single cell you want to start from (D4 in your example) and this function will calculate the sum of the cone as you described.

```
Public Function SUMCONE(r As Range) As Double
    Application.Volatile
    SUMCONE = Application.Sum(r, r(-0, -0).Resize(, 3), r(-1, -1).Resize(, 5), r(-2, -2).Resize(, 7))
End Function
```

Here is an example of how to use the above function from your VBA routine:

```
Public Sub Demo()
    Dim j&
    For j = 5 To 10
        If Cells(5, j) > 0 Then
            Debug.Print SUMCONE(Cells(5, j))
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

**UPDATE**

Based on your feedback I have updated the function and the demo routine to form an upward cone summation from the initial cell.

**UPDATE #2**

The above is for a fixed-size cone, extending upwards, that can be initiated from any cell in the worksheet.

But if you would prefer for the cone to always extend all the way up to row 1 regardless of which cell it originates in,  then the following is what you are after:

```
Public Sub Demo()
    Dim i&, j&
    For j = 1 To Application.CountA(Worksheets("Data").Rows(1))
        For i = 1 To Application.CountA(Worksheets("Data").Columns(1))
            If Cells(i, j) > 0 Then
                Debug.Print Cells(i, j).Address, SumAndColorCone(Cells(i, j))
            End If
        Next
    Next
End Sub

Public Function SumAndColorCone(r As Range) As Double
    Dim i&, k&, c As Range
    Set c = r
    For i = r.Row - 1 To 1 Step -1
        Set c = Union(c, r(-k, -k).Resize(, (k + 1) * 2 + 1))
        k = k + 1
    Next
    c.Interior.Color = vbRed
    SumAndColorCone = Application.Sum(c)
End Function
```

**UPDATE #3**

As I suspected there was a problem if the cone was initiated too close to the left edge of the worksheet. I've added code to handle that now. Also your method for accessing the large matrix (which I had used in the Demo routine) did not work properly. I fixed that as well:

```
Public Sub Demo()
    Dim i&, j&
    For j = 1 To Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        For i = 1 To Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
            If Val(Cells(i, j)) > 0 Then
                Debug.Print Cells(i, j).Address, SumAndColorCone(Cells(i, j))
            End If
        Next
    Next
End Sub

Public Function SumAndColorCone(r As Range) As Double
    Dim i&, k&, c As Range
    Set c = r
    For i = r.Row - 1 To 1 Step -1
        If r.Column - k < 2 Then Exit For
        Set c = Union(c, r(-k, -k).Resize(, (k + 1) * 2 + 1))
        k = k + 1
    Next
    c.Interior.Color = vbRed
    SumAndColorCone = Application.Sum(c)
End Function
```

Comment: thanks, I want to be able to do this for any cell in a matrix that's value is greater than 0. Is it possible to use this function in a loop or similar?

Comment: Just call this function, passing the cell (any cell you choose from your matrix) and this function will calculate the sum of the cone extending leftward from that cell.

Comment: PV1 = SUMCONE(Range("D5"))

Comment: Will the function work if taken to row AZ for example or will I have to set the resize and r to suit these limits for each individual row? Also you said this sums leftward. I want to sum upward to A row

Comment: You are confused. In Excel, rows are numbered and columns are labeled with letters. So D5 means the cell at the intersection of the 4th column and the 5th row. As such your description in this question was clearly for a leftward cone. And yes, it can be used anywhere on the sheet as long as the initial cell is far enough from the top and left so that there are enough cells to form the cone. I CAN REORIENT IT SO THAT THE CONE GOES UPWARDS... DO YOU WANT ME TO DO THAT?

Comment: To be clear, you do not need to fiddle with the function. Call it with any initial cell that is at least four cells away from edge of the sheet and it will work.

Comment: Sorry!! yes I had My orientation wrong I want to project the sum toward row 1! I want to be able to do this using a dynamic function that will assess  every cell in a large matrix and if the sum to using a cone shape row 1. This could have to be called from row 5 or row 150 so I am hoping to build the model so it uses a count function as shown in my code to perform this sum on every cell in a large matrix that has a value >1

Comment: @PatDillon This is precisely what my answer does. It can be called from row 5 or row 150 or even row 1000000. You do not need to change anything in the function.

Comment: I have been re-reading this many times to try to understand what you want. Are you now saying that the cone is NOT a fixed size, that it will always calculate up to row one from however deep it is started from?

Comment: Have you tried the updated code? This is exactly what the two procedures at the bottom of my answer do.

Comment: Thanks, that is what I am trying to do, however when I run your code as it works through     
For i = r.Row - 1 To 1 Step -1
        Set c = Union(c, r(-k, -k).Resize(, (k + 1) * 2 + 1))
        k = k + 1
    Next
It displays the error code Application defined or object defined error?

Comment: It's late here. I'll look in the morning. It's probably an edge case. Try adjusting the demo routine to start calling a couple of rows down and a few columns away from the left border.

Comment: @PatDillon Please see Update #3.